# MYSQL: covert a table of IDs into a table of names

Tags: mysql

Can someone help me on this SQL practice?

**Movie ( mID, title, year, director )** 
Definition: There is a movie with ID number mID, a title, a release year, and a director.

**Reviewer ( rID, name )** 
Definition: The reviewer with ID number rID has a certain name.

**Rating ( rID, mID, stars, ratingDate )** 
Definition: The reviewer rID gave the movie mID a number of stars rating (1-5) on a certain ratingDate.

For all pairs of reviewers such that both reviewers gave a rating to the same movie, return the names of both reviewers. Eliminate duplicates, don't pair reviewers with themselves, and include each pair only once. For each pair, return the names in the pair in alphabetical order.

---

I wrote following query to get pairs of reviewers' ID, but was struggled to get an efficient way to get both reviewers' names in a table:

```
select distinct r1.rID as rID1, r2.rID as rID2
from Rating r1, Rating r2
where r1.rID < r2.rID
and r1.mID = r2.mID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ditch the old school comma syntax for the join operation, and use the `JOIN` keyword instead.

We will need two references to the reviewer table, one for each of the reviewers on the row.

```
 SELECT n1.name    AS r1_name
      , n2.name    AS r2_name

   FROM rating r1

   JOIN rating r2
     ON r1.mid  = r2.mid     -- reviewed the same movie 
    AND r1.rid <> r2.rid     -- don't pair reviewer with themselves (different reviewer)

   JOIN reviewer n1 
     ON n1.rid = r1.rid         

   JOIN reviewer n2 
     ON n2.rid = r2.rid   

  WHERE n1.name < n2.name    -- names in the pair in alphabetical order 

  GROUP
     BY n1.rid
      , n2.rid               -- include each pair of reviewers only once (eliminate duplicates) 

  ORDER
     BY n1.name
      , n2.name              -- result set more deterministic
```

---

> "... it is best to adopt a consistent convention, such as always creating and referring to databases and tables using lowercase names. This convention is recommended for maximum portability and ease of use."

MySQL Reference Manual

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html

**EDIT**

Changed `GROUP BY` to be on reviewer `rid` rather than by `name`.

This will return each "pair of reviewers" only one time.  If two or more reviewers have the same name, then the query could potentially return rows that have the same pairs of names, but those rows will represent different pairs of reviewers.

Comment: Yeah, as I was driving home just now I realised the appropriate place for the name comparison was in a where clause.

Comment: @Nick... or, I could have changed `WHERE` to `AND` and incorporated the predicate into the inner join for `n2`.  (But if I had done that, I would have swapped the comparison around the other way, `AND n2.name > n1.name` , in keeping with the convention I follow.)

Comment: Yes - either way better than the subquery I put in. Oh well, at least I said it might not have been the most efficient solution! :)

Comment: Eliminating duplicates this way is just asking for trouble.

Comment: @Strawberry: Are you maybe referring to the possibility of "duplicate" `name` values....  we could include the `rid` columns in the `GROUP BY`, that fix would potentially return duplicate names, and not satisfy the specification. Or maybe you meant using `GROUP BY` to collapse rows to eliminate duplicates. That's a common SQL pattern, unless you are referring to a MySQL-specific extension, non-standard behavior when `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` is omitted from `sql_mode`, with expressions that are non-aggregate and not functionally dependent... not sure what you mean by "asking for trouble"

Comment: We can point out that if `name` is not guaranteed to be unique, and two (or more) reviewer rows have the sane value for `name`, the query in this example will return fewer rows than if had included the unique identifier for reviewer. That is, this query isn't returning distinct pairs of reviewer rows, it's returning only distinct pairs of name values from reviewer rows. A subtle (but important) distinction. (The specification says to return "each pair" only once. I took "pair" to mean the "pair of reviewer names" being returned, not each "pair" of reviewers with potentially matching names.)